# Does "mysql" user exist in MySQL database system?

Tags: linux, users, mysql

I searched `mysql.user` table and did not find any user named as `mysql`. `root` is the default username.

- I am curious to know whether `mysql` user exists or not? If yes, what is the purpose of this user?
- Does it exist on the OS level instead of the database level?

Answer (score 0):

Usually an OS user-account `mysql` is created at installation time. This is the user that runs the mysql-daemon.

Most packages that come with a daemon will create their own user-account to prevent interference or security issues between different packages.

A user called `mysql` is not created automatically within the database.

Answer (score 0):

The *users* listed in the MySQL `user` table are different from the operating system (login) accounts, though the same *names* may be used.

For instance, a typical MySQL database has a **`root`** user which is the administrator.  But its password is stored in the MySQL database while the operating system stores its password in `/etc/shadow` (or, rarely, `/etc/passwd` now).

MySQL users can be granted privileges, e.g., subsets of the rights possessed by the root user.  These privileges are within the database itself, not related to the file-permissions of the operating system.

The *names* used for MySQL database users need not have any relationship to the *table* names in the database.  This is different from the Oracle database, which stores *tables* within *schemas* which correspond to *users*.  Oracle users also have passwords and (like MySQL) can be granted privileges.  Like Oracle, MySQL user privileges can be limited to tables.

Further reading:

- [MySQL User Account Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-account-management.html) *MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual*
- [The MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-system.html) *MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual*
- [Differences between Database and Schema using different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869522/differences-between-database-and-schema-using-different-databases)
- [Difference between a user and a schema in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle)
- [Schema vs User](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:974699100346868838) *Ask Tom*